# Should i save images to local storage in iOS App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, local-storage

I am working on a project where i want to make the data, text, images available in offline mode as well.

I fetch data from a web-service which includes image urls and other data. I store the text data in core data entities, however i don't save images locally but fetch them in realtime.

To view images in offline mode i will have to save them to local storage. However i am wondering if it would be the right approach. Saving images to local may possibly eat up a lot of storage on user's device.

What is the best approach to address this problem?

Should i save images to local or should i fetch them on run time only?

Answer (score 2):

Use NSCache. With NSCache you can set a limit to how many images and so on are cached. See Apple's documentation for more details: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscache?language=objc

Edit:
Never mind NSCache, just save the images as files. NSCache can still save you network usage and allow your app to be more responsive, but it is not what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Isn't the NSCache deleted after the app is restarted?

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I don't know how I missed this. For long term storage, you might as well save the images as files. That's not the only option, you can also use NSUserDefaults, CoreData or SQLite, but saving them as individual files is the simplest and does the job.

Answer (score 1):

**Should i save images to local or should i fetch them on run time only?**

This question for you , you should decide what you need or what is will be more suitable for your app . at any way if you want to cache images i suggest to use this library [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/%20%E2%80%9CSDWebImage%22)

Comment: I agree this is what i should decide. But my question was about the best practice and ideal scenarios. I personally do not like the apps which download data and use my phone storage. But in general would this be okay to download, say 300 mb of images and save them on your application directory for reuse?

Comment: it’s ok , so my vision now changed, and 300 mb of images is too large , so i think you can’t set limitation to cache downloaded images